# Make a phonecall ios xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I currently have a button in a table view. I have a custom cell class and an update cell method.

```
public void UpdateCell (string subtitle2)
{               
    call.SetTitle(subtitle2, UIControlState.Normal);
    call.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("tel:" + subtitle2));
    };          
}
```

However, when i run this segment of code, i get an error.

> Could not initialize an instance of the type
>   'MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrl': the native 'initWithString:' method
>   returned nil. It is possible to ignore this condition by setting
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void UpdateCell (string subtitle2)
{
    //Makes a new NSUrl
    var callURL = new NSUrl("tel:" + subtitle2);

    call.SetTitle(subtitle2, UIControlState.Normal);
    call.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl (callURL)) {
    //After checking if phone can open NSUrl, it either opens the URL or outputs to the console.

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(callURL);
    } else {
    //OUTPUT to console

    Console.WriteLine("Can't make call");
    }
  };          
}
```

Not sure if phone calls can be simulated in the iPhone Simulator, otherwise just connect your device :-)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in other answers, `NSUrl` cannot handle spaces (and some other symbols) in URL string. That symbols should be encoded before passing to the `NSUrl` constructor. You can do the encoding with the `NSString.CreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` method.
Another way is using of the .NET `Uri` class:

```
new NSUrl(new Uri("tel:" + subtitle2).AbsoluteUri)
```

The issue you might encounter here is parsing of the schema by the `Uri` class. To avoid it, don't use `://`, so, URL strings should look as `"tel:(123) 345-7890"`, not as `"tel://(123) 345-7890"`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("tel://" + subtitle2));
```

Comment: It's still giving me the same error  Could not initialize an instance of the type 'MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrl': the native 'initWithString:' method returned nil.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that calling `initWithString:` returned `nil`. ObjC `init*` methods can return `nil` while .NET constructors can't (and throws).

In general ObjC returns `nil` on `init*` selectors when the input parameters are invalid. In this case I *suspect* your URL format is invalid.

What's the content of your `subtitle2` variable ?

Comment: my format was (###) ###-####. it only accepts ##########

Comment: this is a good explanation "why" getting the exception which a little confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the same problem, after trying various ways, by finally figuring out that there should not be any spaces (instead of e.g. `1800 111 222 333`, should be like `1800111222333`) between numbers to make call in iOS.

```
number = number.Replace(" ", "");

NSUrl url = new NSUrl(string.Format(@"telprompt://{0}", number));
return UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
```